# Override Foreign Key and Unique constraint creation in Hibernate Spring Boot

Tags: java, mysql, spring, database, hibernate

I have below Hibernate relations in a spring boot application.

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "projects")
public class Project {
    
    @Embedded
    private ProjectParameters parameters;
        
}
    
@Embeddable
public class ProjectParameters {
    @Column(name = "hvacConfigs")
    @ElementCollection(targetClass = HVACUserConfigModel.class)
    @CollectionTable(uniqueConstraints = @UniqueConstraint(columnNames = {}), foreignKey = ForeignKey(name = "project_hvacConfig_fk"))
        private Set<HVACUserConfigModel> hvacConfigs;
}
    
@Entity
@Table(name = "hvacuserconfig")
public class HVACUserConfigModel {
    
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Integer id;
        
}
```

Mysql table auto-generated is as follows. Please open images in these below links as I don't have 10 reputation to post images on stackoverflow.

[image: Table]

[image: Foreign_Keys]

[image: Unique Constraints]

[image: Select Query Results]

The issue is I am able to save multiple projects with same project like below

```
Project_uid | hvacConfigs_id
------------------------------
  1001      | 1
  1001      | 2
```

Adding (1002 | 1) throws unique constraint violation.

I am able to get it working by changing table definition explicitly using mysql workbench by removing the unique constrain **UK_me0ekntab0gknshag0xjjv35x**. To remove unique constrain I have to first remove foreign key constrain **FKeygabcnr2stdchxqpb5wuinf2** which is being referred by unique constrain. After these changes, I from spring boot app, I insert new rows it is successfully added with values *(1002 | 1)* & *(1002 | 2)*.

I am able to explore that **@CollectionTable** annotation, annotated in **hvacConfigs** field in Java code, provides ways to insert uniqueConstraint and foreignKey definition as part of attribute definition. I have tried tweaking these attributes of annotation but with no success.

Please let me know if you have any solution how to override the unique constraint and foreign key constraints using java code so that this works without any manual adjustment to mysql table explictly.

Answer (score 0):

To be honest, this is unclear what you want to achieve. But your mapping is invalid. You can use `@ElementCollection` annotation only with [basic or embeddable types](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.4/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#collections-value). If you want operate with `HVACUserConfigModel` as with an entity you should use [@OneToMany](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.4/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#associations-one-to-many) association.

So, you can correct your mapping in this way:

```java
@Embeddable
public class ProjectParameters {

    @ElementCollection
    @CollectionTable(
        name = "hvacuserconfig",
        joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "hvacConfigs_id")
    )
    private Set<HVACUserConfigModel> hvacConfigs;
}
    
@Embeddable
public class HVACUserConfigModel {
   
   // @Id annotation is not used with @Embeddable types
   // Like basic types, embeddable types do not have any identity,
   // being managed by their owning entity.
   private Integer id;
   // ...        
}
```

or in this way:

```java
@Embeddable
public class ProjectParameters {
    
   @OneToMany
   @JoinColumn(name = "hvacConfigs_id") 
   private Set<HVACUserConfigModel> hvacConfigs;
}
    
@Entity
@Table(name = "hvacuserconfig")
public class HVACUserConfigModel {
    
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Integer id;
        
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the edit and reply. Actually we don't want Project info be saved on side of HVACUserConfigModel. That's why we have had ElementCollection which automatically creates another table. However we got to know later that ElementCollection creates a unique index on target table.

Answer (score 0):

We solved this using ManytoMany annotation instead of ElementCollection annotation. It works the same way creating new intermediate table to contain Project Id and HVACUserConfigModel id but does not create the unique index.